# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{x^{x}}-x^x$ using a graph

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

I came across a question

$$\lim_{x\to 0} x^{x^{x}}-x^x$$

I tried plotting the graph, but graph of $x^x$ doesn't exist but $x^{x^x}$ which is quite indigestible.

When I plotted the graph for $x^{x^x} - x^x$ then this graph exists which gives $-1$ at $x=0$, so I'm totally confused and not able to comprehend it.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: What do you mean by "the graph doesn't exist"?  Provided we agree upon $0^0=1$, we get $0^{0^0}-0^0=0^1-1=-1$.

Comment: We don't have to agree on $0^0=1$, in this context: $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out the limit for
$$\lim_{x\to 0} x^x$$
$$x=e^{\ln x} \rightarrow \lim_{x\to 0}x^x=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\ln x^x} = \lim_{x\to 0}e^{x\ln x}=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\frac{\ln x}{\frac1x}}$$
Apply L'hospital for $\frac{\ln x}{\frac1x}$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}e^{x}\rightarrow1$$
Now
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x^{x^x}\rightarrow e^{x^x\ln x}$$
We know $\lim_{x\to 0}x^x=1$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\ln x}=\lim_{x\to 0}x=0$$
Hence $x^{x^x}-x^x=-1$

Answer (score 3):

Here is the graph for $x^x$: [Graph of $x^x$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pygoqqcpcg)

[And the graph of $x^{x^x}$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z2xslm8bao)

[Finally, the graph of $x^{x^x} -x^x$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o5kljbcdns)

Yes, you're correct that at $x=0$ we have the value of graph as $-1$, but please notice that the graph isn't defined for negative $x$, it is because $x^x$ is imaginary if $x$ is negative and not an integer. For example, let's take $x= -1/4$, then we have
$$
x^x = (-1/4)^{-1/4} \\
x^x = \frac{1}{ 
                \left(
                        \left(
                           \frac{-1}{4}\right
                                         )^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}}
$$
Clearly, the square root (that is 1/2 power) of a negative number is imaginary.

So, we don't have left hand limit defined for $\lim_{x \to 0} x^{x^x} -x^x$ and hence the limit doesn't exist. The correct way to write our observation is
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} x^{x^x} -x^x = -1
$$

Hope it helps in some way!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to avoid complex numbers, we should look at $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$.

We are going to use two things, $a^b = e^{b\ln a}$ and $\lim_{x\to a} e^{f(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}$.

Thus, $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x = \lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{x\ln x} = e^{\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x\ln x)}.\tag{1}$$

Now, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x\ln x)$ is of the form $0\cdot (-\infty)$, so special care is needed. We could write it in the form $\frac{\ln x}{1/x}$ and use l'Hospital's rule to conclude that the limit is $0$. Returning to $(1)$ we get

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x = e^0 = 1.\tag{2}$$

So, $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{x^x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{x^x \ln x} = e^{\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x^x \ln x)} = \left[e^{1\cdot(-\infty)} = e^{-\infty}\right] = 0.\tag{3}$$

Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ gives us $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x^{x^x}-x^x) = 0 - 1 = -1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)= x$ and $g(x)= x^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb {R^+}$ . Notice that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} g(x) $ does exist which is $1$ and non-zero   so $$\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x))^{g(x)}-g(x)) =\lim_{x\to 0}  f(x)^{g(x)} - \lim_{x\to 0} g(x) =  \lim_{x\to 0} (f(x))^1-1= 0-1=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Since you already received good answers and that you play with the graph, let me continue further that the limit itself.

Composing Taylor series
$$x^x=1+x \log (x)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log ^2(x)+\frac{1}{6} x^3 \log ^3(x)+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$x^{x^x}=x+x^2 \log ^2(x)+\frac{1}{2} x^3 \left(\log ^4(x)+\log ^3(x)\right)+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$x^{x^x}-x^x=-1+x (1-\log (x))+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log ^2(x)+\frac{1}{6} x^3 \log ^3(x) (3 \log
   (x)+2)+O\left(x^4\right)$$

Plot the lhs and the rhs on the same graph. They almost overlap for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ (the maximum error is $0.0035$)

Comment: Wow never thought about using Taylor series thanks alot